# Having trouble adding image to GitHub pages

Tags: github-pages

I cannot add images to my GitHub pages, I've tried a lot of solutions I found on the internet, such as

```
![LSTM]({{ site.url }}/{{ site.baseurl }}/docs/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png)
![lstm unit]({{ site.baseurl }}/docs/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png)
![lstm unit]({{ site.url }}/docs/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png)
```

nothing works. 
The error I received most is

> '/blog/docs/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png' not found.

The strangest thing is when I use

```
![lstm unit](../images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png)
```

I get an error

> `/blog/machine learning/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png' not found.

But I don't have any `/blog/machine learning` directory. I guess it has something to do with my setting the categories and tags to `machine learning` in the input YAML Front Matter. So I tried to remove them, then I cannot open my essay on the Jekyll service at all. It says

> `/blog/machine learning/LSTM-and-its-variants/' not found.

but I put my essay in `docs/_posts`...

What on earth is going on here? Please help me sort this out, Thanks.
In case you need, my GitHub is built on `docs` directory, and images are in `docs/images/LSTM/` directory

### UPDATE

Finally, I got it worked by using below code

```
![LSTM]({{ '/images/lstm/architecture.png' | absolute_url }})
```

This is quite different from the solutions I found online, is anybody could help me explain it?

Comment: where are the images in your repo structure?

Comment: the image is in `/docs/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png`/

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path to your resources, without all the prefixed site urls.

```
![LSTM](/docs/images/LSTM/lstm-unit.png)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This may be my first few trials and I'm sorry to say that this doesn't work...

Comment: are you able to find where you can navigate to the image directly? It would help figuring out what the link should be if you can discover where the url exists!

Comment: ahh i see your edit to your question @SherwinChen- its totally acceptable to post an answer to your own question if you figured it out!

Comment: Although I figured it out, I don't know what's going on here :(. Could you help me sort this out? It's my first time to build a blog, and I'm not very familiar with the corresponding languages

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the point. I shouldn't look the directory where the image stores on my local computer, I should find where it stores on the site, ie.  `_site` when using jekyll service